# Directing User to Home page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I want user to divert to home page when user types

```
www.xxxxxx.com/myapp
```

Currently i have to type

```
www.xxxxxx.com/myapp/home.aspx
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: you should set default page in your web server to be home.aspx. Are you using IIS?

Comment: I did, and i upload web app to the server. But when i do www.xxxxx.com/myapp, it doesnot work

Comment: what version of IIS are you using?

Comment: _"does not work"_ is not an error. What's in the logs?

Comment: check this http://visioncreationlink.com/locker and thishttp://visioncreationlink.com/test

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple index.html file and put this code in it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 location = '/myapp/home.aspx';
</script>
```

This is just an **alternative solution** when you can't change your codes and server default page.

- This solution will not work if JavaScript is disabled.
- You can create a default.aspx page and just use response.redirect("/myapp/home.aspx");

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

1) Configure home.aspx as default page in IIS

2) Create a default.aspx in the same folder containing code to redirect to home.aspx

3) Use the IIS Rewriting 2.0 Module to redirect the request

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to put an index.html page in directory and put in some JavaScript... To redirect to your page... It's not the best solution but it works if you don't want to change settings in IIS....

Answer (score 0):

In web.config add following under `system.webserver` tag:

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="home.aspx"/>
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```